# Python pkg_resources.get_distribution alternative

Tags: python, pkg-resources

I have some code that's extremely slow, I've traced it back to the use of `pkg_resources.get_distribution`, I'm doing this:

```
# ...
pkg_resources.get_distribution(module_name).version
```

Is there an alternative library/method I can use that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the module you are working with, most python libraries implement the `__version__` attribute, try that:

My timings also suggest it is the best. I tried with three different methods:

```
import time
import pip
import pkg_resources
from pip.operations import freeze


# __version__
t0 = time.time()
version_number = pip.__version__
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print("__version__ =", version_number, "in", total)

# pip freeze
t0 = time.time()
x = freeze.freeze()

for p in x:
    if p[:p.find('==')] == "pip":
        version_number = p[p.find('==')+2:]
        break
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print("pip freeze =", version_number, "in", total)

# pkg_resources
t0 = time.time()
version_number = pkg_resources.get_distribution("pip").version
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print("pkg_resources =", version_number, "in", total)
```

Keep in mind that the `pip freeze` method will be highly variable in timing, depending on how many modules you have in your system.

Results:

```
__version__ = 9.0.1 in 2.1457672119140625e-06
pip freeze = 9.0.1 in 0.04388904571533203
pkg_resources = 9.0.1 in 0.0016148090362548828
```

On my system `__version__` was 7.5 times faster than `pkg_resources`

Comment: I guess what I don't quite understand is what `pkg_resources.get_distribution` is actually doing? Is it looking at something other than `module.__version__`?

Comment: No it doesn't, have a look over here: [pkg_resources.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/pkg_resources.py)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that using `module.__version__` is a 100% like-for-like replacement for my code, as I only have a list of module names as strings and they may not have been imported